How to implement zero-knowledge encryption with SSO?
I am developing an application, that supports single-sign-on (SSO) with external identity providers such as Google, Apple, GitHub, and others.
Now I want to store user data end-to-end encrypted, so that only the user can access it (zero-knowledge).
Therefore I would use a Password-Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF2) to create a key, that is used to encrypt a private key that can then be stored in my user DB.
When the user logs in, the PBKDF key is re-generated from the password (and salt) and used (with another salt) to decrypt the stored private key.
With a email/password-based login, this is perfectly clear.
But what do I do when the user signs in via SSO?
In that case, the actual password is only known to the identity provider and there is nothing I can use as password to create a PBKDF key.

My first thought was to use a user ID (like the sub by Google or user by Apple) and send an authenticated request to my server, that generates the password from the user ID, salt and server secret.
But there is one big design flaw: I could just bypass the authentication and use the user ID to generate the password - so the user data would not be safe.

So how do I implement a zero-knowledge encryption with SSO without that the user has to set an extra password to encrypt the data?

I don't think SSO in general gives you this option. There's no particular reason why it could not, but in general, the identity provider simply tells you (the relying party) that user X really is talking to you.

@K.G. I think you are right. Currently I think having to assign an additional password might even increase trust in the encryption. So that might even be a good thing :)
